# Where do I start to investigate when phoenix live reload stops working after upgrading to Phoenix 1.0?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I just upgraded my project to Phoenix 1.0. For some reason phoenix live reload stopped working when I changed my files. Is there a place where I should look first to try to gain some insight on why it stopped working? Here is what my mix.exs looks like:

```
defp deps do
[{:phoenix, "~> 1.0"},
 {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.1"},
 {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0"},
 {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
 {:shouldi, only: :test},
 {:meck, "~> 0.8.3"}]
```

end

Comment: You are upgrading from which version? Do you see anything in your browser console? Anything in your terminal? Have you changed editors or installed a new plugin lately?

Comment: I upgraded to phoenix 1.0 from .15. Nothing happens in the terminal when I save a file (an *.ex file). I'm still using the same editor (Atom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked in your config/dev.exs file and seen (similar):

```
# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :polyvox, Polyvox.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$},
      ~r{web/views/.*(ex)$},
      ~r{web/templates/.*(eex)$}
    ]
  ]
```